# NetLogo AgentSet substraction

Tags: netlogo

I got the error message:

```
MEMBER? expected input to be a string or list or agentset but got the number 0 instead.
```

during running following NetLogo Code:

```
to find-flockmates  ;; turtle reporter
  ;; latch on to the nearby birds
  set flockmates-infront other birds in-cone vision cone-infront-degree
  set flockmates-sidewise other birds in-cone vision cone-sidewise-degree

  ;; agentset substraction
  if (count flockmates-infront > 0)[
    set flockmates-sidewise (flockmates-sidewise with [not member? self flockmates-infront])  
    ] 
end
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong or another possible solution for a substraction of two agentsets?

Comment: Maybe there is something I am not seeing, but it seems like you're doing it right... Do you get this error every time, or only under special conditions? Have you tried `show flockmates-infront` to see if it's ever set to anything but an agentset? (As far as I can tell, it shouldn't. It could be `nobody` but your `if` would take care of that.)

Comment: this error is fired every time, except when I create less birds/turtles than 10.

Comment: Weird. Would you mind posting your complete model somewhere?

Comment: have fun ;) [link](http://megastore.uni-augsburg.de/get/29cYLUoyv8/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see, now! Tough it could possibly have been guessed from the initial code sample you posted, I did not realize at first that `flockmates-sidewise` and `flockmates-infront` were breed variables.

As a consequence, in this line:

```
set flockmates-sidewise (flockmates-sidewise with [not member? self flockmates-infront])
```

...`flockmates-infront` refers to the breed variable of the agent executing the `with` block, **not** the variable of the agent running the `find-flockmates` reporter. (And that one may very well be `0` if it has not been initialized yet.) What you want is:

```
set flockmates-sidewise (flockmates-sidewise with [
    not member? self [flockmates-infront] of myself
])
```

[`myself`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#myself) means "the turtle or patch who asked me to do what I'm doing right now."

I guess you were not getting the error when creating less than 10 birds because your `if` prevented the line from being executed at all in that case.